# Disable grabbing alt+tab in Citrix

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, citrix, alt-tab

(I used to use NX client, which does not grab <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, so with NX I could to switch windows with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> on my host OS only, which is prefered for me.)

I had to switch Citrix, which grabs this (alt-tab) keys (only in fullscreen mode) so if Citrix is active I cannot switch to any other host window (using keys), which is not preferred for me.

**I want to switch windows with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> on my host OS only.**

My Citrix host is Win7, guest is a RH6. Version is 4.9

Comment: Best alternative is using Citrix in windowed mode, with huge window.

Answer (score 2):

**Symptoms or Error**

Executing ALT+TAB keys toggles opened applications on endpoint machine instead of desktop session

**Solution**

Launch `Regedit.exe` on the client device to edit the registry

**For `Windows 32-bit` OS**, navigate to the key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SOFTWARE\Citrix\ICAClient\Engine\Lockdown Profiles\All Regions\Lockdown\Virtual Channels\Keyboard\

**For `Windows 64-bit` OS**, navigate to the key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Citrix\ICA Client\Engine\Lockdown Profiles\All Regions\Lockdown\Virtual Channels\Keyboard\

**In some cases configuring User based Setting** also helps:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Citrix\ICAClient\Engine\Lockdown Profiles\All Regions\Lockdown\Virtual Channels\Keyboard\

```
Value Name    TransparentKeyPassthrough
Value Type    REG_SZ
Value         Remote
```

The Value "Remote" will enable it and blank will disable it

Comment: Does not help ;(

Comment: I just tested this with Citrix Receiver 4.12 (64-bit) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This made Alt-Tab switch consistently on the host, for me:

(both in Window mode and Full-screen mode)

In registry, within:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Citrix\ICA
> Client\Engine\Lockdown Profiles\All Regions\Lockdown\Virtual
> Channels\Keyboard

I changed:

> TransparentKeyPassthrough = Local

(was empty)

Win10, 64-bit, Citrix Workspace 19.3.0.4